# Convolutional Neural Network for outlier detection

Tags: neural-network, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network, anomaly-detection

Lets say I have the cifar 10 dataset and I manipulate it in such a way that I reduce the number of frogs in the dataset from 6000 to say 600. I now consider frog as an outlier and train a two class classification problem on this modified cifar 10 dataset. All the other 9 classes as one group and the frog as a outlier. What architecture is best to detect this frog outlier? Where can I find reading materials to learn about these?

Comment: Just have your classifier produce probabilities. Then build a AUC ROC curve and choose a threshold you find appropriate for outlier detection.